# iOS Push Notification .p12 file lost

Tags: ios, notifications, push, bundle, updates

I have an ios application in app store, it has push notifications activated but now I've lost my p12 file. I have access to generate a new .p12 but can't get the old. I've done a new app that is going to be an update of that that is on app store and want to send it push notifications too. This two apps must have the same bundle identifier.

The question is: 
What can I do to still continue receiving push notifications on my app that is on app store and in the new one?